Sphinx generate documentation based on two separate sys.path
I have the following structure to be rendered as documentation
index.rst:
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Feature Family

   feature/modules.rst



.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Extract

   extract/modules.rst


feature/modules.rst:
feature
=======

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3

   app_package
   call_logs
   contact_list
   sms_logs
   user


extract/modules.rst:
extract
=======

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3

   app_packages
   call_logs
   contact_list
   sms_logs
   user
   users


Now feature/modules.rst and extract/modules.rst have these subcategory folder names as common:
call_logs, contact_list, sms_logs , user  which is why sphinx is getting confused with which sys.path to use when building their corresponding documentation. Currently my conf.py has following definitions:
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../feature_service/feature'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../feature_service/extract'))

Only if I were to remove ../../feature_service/extract from sys.path then the documentation from ../../feature_service/feature would be generated correctly, because the name of subfolders under these categories are same overlapping I am suspecting sphinx is confused in which directory to look at when using autodoc Is There any workaround for this? Changing name of the folders to be different would work but is not recommended

Found a solution. Because of subfolder having common names i decided to do the following:

Update the sys.path to only include these:

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../feature_service'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../feature_service/feature'))
## Exclude `extract` intentionally
#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../feature_service/extract'))


Update the sub-.rst files under extract/modules.rst to locate the directories properly, example adding a prefix extract. like following:

.. automodule:: extract.app_packages.v0_1.extract
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

.. automodule:: extract.app_packages.v0_1
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:


